# How can I flow a series of elements around an "absolutely positioned" element?

Tags: css, css-float, css-position

Here's the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RkMFK/

Here's the html and css:

```
<div class="cont">

<div class="item">one</div>
<div class="item">two</div>
<div class="item">three</div>
<div class="item">four</div>
<div class="item">five</div>
<div class="item">six</div>
<div class="item">seven</div>
<div class="item">eight</div>
<div class="item">nine</div>
<div class="item">ten</div>
<div class="item">eleven</div>
<div class="item">twelve</div>
<div class="item">thirteen</div>
<div class="item">fourteen</div>
<div class="item">fifteen</div>
<div class="item">sixteen</div>
<div class="item">seventeen</div>
<div class="item">eighteen</div>

<div class="island"></div>

</div>​

.cont {
    width: 240px;
    height: 160px;
    background-color:blue;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.island {
    position:absolute;
    top:50px;
    left:80px;
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
    background-color:red;
}

.item {
    float:left;
    display:inline;
    position:relative;
    height:20px;
    margin:2px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    background-color:yellow;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

How can I make the yellow items flow around the red "island" with css?

Summary: I have a container div of a fixed dimension.  Somewhere within it is a small "island" div at a specific location (currently positioned absolutely, which removes it from the flow).  How can I fill the container with a number of small elements of unknown width that surround the island?  Any way to do this with css only?  I'm stuck.

Comment: Quick answer: no (but welcome to SO anyway).

Answer (score 0):

May be you want some what like in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RkMFK/1/) . If i am lagging some where please let me know. so i can work out..

code:html

```
<div class="cont">

<div class="island"></div>
<div class="item">one</div>
<div class="item">two</div>
<div class="item">three</div>
<div class="item">four</div>
<div class="item">five</div>
<div class="item">six</div>
<div class="item">seven</div>
<div class="item">eight</div>
<div class="item">nine</div>
<div class="item">ten</div>
<div style="margin:0 20px" class="item">eleven</div>
<div style="margin:0 25px" class="item">twelve</div>
<div class="item">thirteen</div>
<div style="margin-left:58px;" class="item">fourteen</div>
<div class="item">fifteen</div>
<div class="item">sixteen</div>
<div class="item">seventeen</div>
<div class="item">eighteen</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but won't quite work for my situation.  I know in advance the size and location of the "island", but the "item" content is dynamic - generated by db queries - don't know the size or number of them, so can't customize the css like this.